# Dataframe search for words and append them in a new column, plus iterate over a list of words

Tags: python, dataframe, append, apply

I am new to python so I apologize if I missed something obvious. I have a dataframe of newspaper articles, and the text is stored in `df['text']`.
I would like to see if each article contains specific words that I keep in a list, and append each occurence in a new column `df['words']`.

I've been trying the code below, but it returns True/False in the new column and not the word themselves.

```
list_words = ['apple','banana','orange']

for word in list_words:   
    df['words'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: pd.notna(x) and word in x)
```

Could someone please help me figure out how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend of mine got me the perfect answer, using regular expressions:

```
def get_words(text):
    words_found = []
    for word in list_words:
        if re.search(word, text):
            words_found.append(word)
        else:
            continue
        return words_found

df['words'] = df['document'].apply(get_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_word(text):
    temp=[]
    for word in list_words:
        if word in text:
            temp.append(word)
    return temp
    
df['words']=df['text'].apply(find_word)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However df['word']=word applies the value word to all lines, not line by line. Plus, if a word is spotted in the text, I'd like to append this word to df['word'] instead of replacing the former value.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback try the above code I have changed it according to your suggestion I hope this will work for you

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Yes of course actually apply() method lets you apply an arbitrary function to the data frame the function take each row (or record) and apply the function on it so here we use apply() function to find the words in text and the function return the list of words and the list get allocated to the word column of the row passed as argument to apply() function.